# Locked out of admin panel after update

Tags: updates, manual-updates

I updated a very old Craft installation (v2.6.2794 to v2.6.2971) and now I'm locked out off the admin area. I can get to the login panel and log in but once in I just get 500 errors.

After turning on devMode, I found this:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /mysite.com/craft/app/helpers/ModelHelper.php on line 102
```

I already have my `phpMaxMemoryLimit` at `512M` (checked). Could my installation really be using that much memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd initially forgotten to turn on devMode to find out what the 500 error was. Once I did that I found out it was exhausting the memory. I had to raise it up to 1024M!

Comment: That's ridiculously high to just log in.  Do you have any plugins installed that might be interfering?  Particularly anything listening to onLogin events or ones that add widgets to the dashboard?

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. Not many plugins and none of them deal with onLogin events. Though it seems it was freezing after logging in, when loading the posts. I'm still investigating the source of this in this other post, http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/php-memory-limit-is-1024-mb-too-much , my server seems to be going through some peaks. I'm afraid it's due to how I've setup the cache.